# display only a time range with plotly.net

Tags: plotly, plotly.net

I have a plotly.net graph with a lot of different shapes.

The X axis is a timeline and I would like to limit the display to a specific range of dates.

I could filter / clamp the data in each shape, etc but that seems like a lot of work compared to setting the display's range to specific values.

I can't find this in the plotly.net docs; does anyone know where that would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not specify if the range of dates should be continuous, so i'll just assume it.

You can simply use the `MinMax` argument of the `withXAxisStyle` function like this:

```fs
open Plotly.NET

let dates = [for i in 1..10 -> System.DateTime.Now.AddYears(i)]
let values = [for i in 1..10 -> double i]

let range_start = System.DateTime.Now.AddYears(2)
let range_end = System.DateTime.Now.AddYears(3)

Chart.Line(
    x = dates, 
    y = values
)
|> Chart.withXAxisStyle(MinMax = (range_start, range_end))
```

As you can see, the dates range from 2025 untill 2026. although the original data goes until 2033.

[image: the produced chart with a date range on the xAxis]